# NodeJS and data transfer between handlers

Tags: node.js, git, handler, discord, node-xmpp

Trying to learn Node and I set a task for me: Transport bot, but have some problems:

I can see chat streams from jabber and discrod chat, but I cant find way to send messages from jabber to discrod or reverse because I do not understand how to implement this.

Can anyone help me with theory and parctice?

My code on git: https://github.com/DiWorm/NodeJS-Bot

Comment: Why do you type `Discrod` and not `Discord` ? And for your question, just use a fonction in your jabber module who will call the Discord module, and same for the other way.

Comment: @ShigehiroKamisama this is a missprint :)
Can you show example?